# Creating Shiny reactive variable that indicates which widget was last modified

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

Let's say we have a set of widgets each with their own input label. How do we create a reactive object whose value is the character that represents the input ID of the last widget that was modified?

For example, if we have

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
   textInput('txt_a', 'Input Text A'),
   textInput('txt_b', 'Input Text B")
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   last_updated_widget <- reactive({
      #hypothetical code that indicates ID value of last updated widget
   })
})
```

The desired result is as follows. If the user modifies the first text box, then the value of `last_updated_widget()` would be `"txt_a"`. If they modify the second box, the value of `last_updated_widget()` becomes `"txt_b"`. I'm in search of a result that extends to the obvious generalization of setting the value to be the ID of any of the widgets that was adjusted last.

I'd like this to work for an arbitrary number of widget inputs, including the case that they were generated by a `renderUI()` statement. So making a separate `reactive()` statement for each widget isn't an option. However, if the reactive statement requires a loop over all the widget names (or something like that) I can certainly work with that. And multiple reactive statements is okay, as long as it's a fixed amount, and not a function of the number of widgets.

It seems like a pretty simple problem, so I was surprised when it became a roadblock for me. I feel like the solution would be really obvious and I'm just not seeing, so if it is, I apologize for making it a new question. But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that works, though it looks a little awkward because of a nested `observe()`. I'm not sure what a better way would be, but there could be something nicer.

Basically, use an `observe()` to loop over all the available inputs, and for each input, use another `observe()` that will only trigger when that input is changed and set a variable to the id of the input.

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      textInput('txt_a', 'Input Text A'),
      textInput('txt_b', 'Input Text B'),
      uiOutput('txt_c_out'),
      verbatimTextOutput("show_last")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$txt_c_out <- renderUI({
      textInput('txt_c', 'Input Text C')
    })

    values <- reactiveValues(
      lastUpdated = NULL
    )

    observe({
      lapply(names(input), function(x) {
        observe({
          input[[x]]
          values$lastUpdated <- x
        })
      })
    })

    output$show_last <- renderPrint({
      values$lastUpdated
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reactive value created with `reactiveValues()` to store the name of the last used widget. Later use an observer to keep track of the activity of each widget and update the reactive value with the name of the last used widget.

In the folowing example, the name of the last used widget is stored in `last_updated_widget$v` and will active the `verbatimTextOutput` each time it changes. You can use `last_updated_widget$v` at any place in the server.

```
    library(shiny)
    runApp(list(
      ui = shinyUI(
            fluidPage(
                textInput('txt_a', 'Input Text A'),
                textInput('txt_b', 'Input Text B'),
                verbatimTextOutput("showLast")
            )
        ),
        server = function(input, output, session) {
            last_updated_widget <- reactiveValues( v = NULL)
            observe ({
                input$txt_a
                last_updated_widget$v <- "txt_a"
            })
            observe ({
                input$txt_b
                last_updated_widget$v <- "txt_b"
            })
            output$showLast <- renderPrint({
                last_updated_widget$v
            })
        }
    ))
```

Comment: I don't think he/she wants a manual solution like that, the original question says it should owrk with an arbitrary number of inputs

Comment: daatali is right, but I edited that detail into the question. If Geovany was already answering before I edited it in, I apologize

Comment: I'm sorry, I was writing the sample code before you updated the question, so I didn't notice the restriction and just paste the code. That feature would be  useful, maybe it will be better to work internally with the shiny core. By the way @daattali your shinyjs library is very useful.